# What tools will I need to remove sprocket/what type will I need to order?

Tags: tools

[image]

I have a flip-flop hub on a single speed track bike.
I need to replace the rear sprocket (freewheel side) and chain.

Id prefer to give this a go myself, but

1. Not sure what tools I need to remove this
2. Not sure what freewheel I would need to order to replace it with.
   (ideally a similar or upgrade.  + points for links to sites like Evans/ChainReactionCycles)

Comment: One thing for sure - you need to claen it :)

Comment: Don't forget some kind of penetrating lube. Solvent-based chain lube or WD-40. Otherwise you have a good chance of shearing the teeth off your new removal tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will be a BMX freewheel tool you will be needing. Order a BMX style freewheel, count the teeth or get one with less/more teeth depending on how you want to be pedalling - higher cadence will need more teeth.

If you have access to a big vice then you can put the freewheel removal tool in that. Otherwise a really big adjustable spanner from some pound-shop will do nicely.

Comment: Doorway works as well...once you have the tool :O

Comment: So this freewheel http://www.wiggle.co.uk/shimano-bmx-freewheel/

And this tool:
http://www.parktool.com/product/freewheel-remover-FR-6

IS all I need? (+door)

Comment: yep. Also remember to use the wheelnut to retain the freewheel removal tool during the initial tug so that the freewheel does not slip against the tool mashing it up.